# 3D wavelet transform in the form of a matrix?

Tags: wavelets

I was wondering if anyone may know of any method for the construction of a 3D wavelet transform in matrix form? I've been able to build matrices to perform 1D & 2D transforms. Yet, am finding very little resources regarding the 3D case in the literature.

Comment: The community at this sister site is quite small but i have found them helpful for any dsp related questions: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks alot for this!